# Powershell variables in Get-AdUser

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to write a simple powershell script.

```
Get-ADuser -Filter {GivenName -eq $GivenName $hateList} -SearchBase $Container -Properties displayName,telephoneNumber,department|ForEach-Object {"FullName`t: $($_.displayName)`r`nPhone`t`t: $($_.telephoneNumber)`r`nDepartment`t: $($_.department)`r`n"}
```

The error what I got:
    Get-ADUser : Error parsing query: 'GivenName -eq $GivenName $hateList' Error Message: 'syntax error' at position: '26'.

So the problem is that the variables aren't substituted with their values. What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Filter parameter is not right. If you want to have GivenName be equal to $GivenName you should do it like this:

```
{GivenName -eq $GivenName}
```

If you want it to be equal to $GivenName or $hateList, whatever it is, you should try something like:

```
{(GivenName -eq $GivenName) -or (GivenName -eq $hateList)}
```

Check this link for more filter:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617241.aspx

You can first get list of users with filter like this:

```
{GivenName -eq $GivenName}
```

And the do some post processing:

```
$users | Where-Object { $hateList -notcontains  $_.cn }
```

Comment: @adam_gav If you are happy with the answer, then please accept it. There's accept checkbox next to it

Comment: Thanks your fast reply!
I would like to check that the GivenName is the same in the variable, and the hateList contains a string something like this:
-and cn -ne "foo" -and cn -ne "bar" -and cn -ne "blabla"
So it would check that the cn not equal with a couple of strings.
How do I put in parentheses ?
I tried to modify to make the hateList the following: -and (cn -ne "foo") -and (cn -ne "bar") -and (cn -ne "blabla")
How can I make the filter? I tried the following, but it of course not working: -Filter {(GivenName -eq $GivenName) $hateList}

Comment: Correct, if you need to verify that GivenName is not one of $hateList then you need to break it to multiple conditions. I don't think -contains works here.

Comment: Actually your suggestion was syntactically not correct, but the bigger problem is the following. I tried it with it:
    {(GivenName -eq "$GivenName") -and ($hateList -notcontains (cn)) }
But it gives an error:
    Error Message: 'Operat
or Not supported: -notcontains' at position: '46'.

Which is not so strange, because notcontains isn't in the documentation of the filter.

Comment: @adam_gav Then you should just stick to GivenName in the Get-ADuser. It will give you list of users that you can then filter according to $hateList. See my latest answer

Comment: I would like to avoid object filtering, because AFAIK it's significantly slower then using AD filtering. Howewer, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

If variable expansion doesn't work when passing the variable, try to pass it enclosed in quotes:

```
{GivenName -eq "$GivenName"}
```

Comment: It's working, but the main problem is hateList. If i understand it I need to make the following: 
    -Filter {(GivenName -eq "blabla") -and (cn -ne "alma") -and (cn -ne "korte") -and (cn -ne "bela")} 
In my context this:
    "(GivenName -eq `"$GivenName`") $hateList"
produces this:
    (GivenName -eq "blabla") -and (cn -ne "alma") -and (cn -ne "korte") -and (cn -ne "bela")

But I couldn't figure out ho can I use t in filter

Comment: You'd probably be better off just using the ldap filter on the GivenName, and then using a PS conditional on the results:  {GivenName -eq $GivenName} | where {$hatelist -notcontains $_.CN}