# how to find active directory user using SAMAccountName attribute in powershell?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to read users from Active directory with following criteria.
I want only the user which samaccountName I have passed.
So how to find active directory user using SAMAccountName attribute in powershell?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Powershell variables in Get-AdUser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680504/powershell-variables-in-get-aduser)

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617241.aspx

Answer (score 0):

dsquery user -samid *samaccountname*

For example: dsquery user -samid jdoe